# Comparing users balances against the sum of their transactions

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables:

(i) a balance table that shows the balance for each of the users

(ii) a transaction table that has the debit and credit transactions for each of the users

I need to check if any user has a discrepancy between his/her balance in the balance table and the sum of his/her transactions in the transaction table.

When I  enter the below query:

```
select sum(transaction.credit)-sum(transaction.debit),balance.balance
from transaction
right join balance on balance.user_id = transaction.user_id
where balance.balance <> sum(transaction.credit)-sum(transaction.debit)
group by transaction.user_id
```

I get an error with a message "Invalid use of group function".  But even if I remove the last row, I still get the same message.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Second point is that this query is absolutely useless, it doesn't help you identify descrepancies. It's output will be a to numbers but there is no way for you to identify what rows those numbers actuallly came from

Comment: @e4c5 the error itself is raised because the OP uses aggregate functions in the where clause.

Comment: oops @shadow, I meant to type projection and not projects :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditions on aggregate functions should not be put in the `where` clause, but in the `having` clause:

```
select      balance.user_id, 
            coalesce(sum(transaction.credit), 0) 
             - coalesce(sum(transaction.debit), 0) trans_balance, 
            balance.balance
from        transaction
right join  balance 
         on balance.user_id = transaction.user_id
group by    balance.user_id
having      balance.balance <> trans_balance
```

Note that it is better to `group by balance.user_id` as there might not be a matching `transaction` record. You should in that case also use `coalesce` as otherwise the comparison will fail on `null`.

Comment: Thank you trincot.  it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

USE `Having` Instead of `Where` clause

```
select transaction.user_id
from transaction
right join balance on balance.user_id = transaction.user_id
group by transaction.user_id
Having sum(transaction.credit)-sum(transaction.debit) <> balance.balance
```

Comment: thanks JaydipJ.  however, I got an error "Unknown column 'balance.balance' in 'having clause'".